# How to create accurately timed soft video sub titles?

Tags: video, vlc, subtitle

I know how to create soft subtitles with a text editor and saving the text file as a srt file.  But it's taking very long and and timing isn't the best as I am starting and stopping the video using vlc to get the start and stop times.

Does a better program exists which makes it easier to create the soft sub titles?  So the timing is a lot easier and simpler to get right?

Comment: Check for gnome subtitle utility in software centre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create/edit/synchronize your subtitles, you can try :

- [Gnome-subtitles](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-subtitles/)
- [Gaupol subtitle editor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gaupol/)
- [Subtitle editor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/subtitleeditor/)

And then [Avidemux](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/avidemux/) to integrate your subtitles in your video

<sub>**Source**: I found these apps from the [French Ubuntu Web Site](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/sous-titrage)</sub>